# pgadmin drop sequence

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

In an SQL script I declare:

```
drop sequence if exists my_sequence_seq cascade;
```

pgadminIII, version 1.14.3 displays the following error:

```
the relation my_sequence_seq already exists
```

I don't see my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The error message doesn't make any sense. That's what you get when trying to create a sequence that already exists.

Maybe some weird mistake in the old version of pgAdmin 1.14.3? Try upgrading to the [current version pgAdmin 1.16.1](http://pgadmin.org/).